media query for min-width:319px) and (max-width:480px) not working on chrome but other browsers while @media(min-width:1601px) is not working anywhere
After the first test, I saw the light salmon not showing in chrome when I resize the screen , then tested out on mobile where it worked fine. Checked my code again for any errors and tested on edge and firefox where the lightsalmon seems to work fine.
Now I am stuck with the seagreen color which works nowhere.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Media Query</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: aquamarine;
    }
    
    @media(min-width:319px) and (max-width:480px) {
      body {
        background-color: lightsalmon;
      }
    }
    
    @media(min-width:481px) and (max-width:1200px) {
      body {
        background-color: powderblue;
      }
    }
    
    @media(min-width:1201px) and (max-width:1600px) {
      body {
        background-color: limegreen;
      }
    }
    
    @media(min-width:1601px) {
      body {
        background-color: seagreen;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>




Can't reproduce - Chrome 125.0.6422.61 64bit and Firefox 126.0 (64-bit)

I have checked and working fine for me.

@Leothelion the seagreen color is being displayed?

@Misslost909 yes i am seeing 4 color while resizing the chrome and in the end, bigger screen, i am seeing seagreen color.

You can use the fact that later rules override earlier ones to simplify your media queries.


body {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  body {
    background-color: powderblue;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    background-color: limegreen;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  body {
    background-color: seagreen;
  }
}



After running this snippet, use the full page link to test the responsiveness.

Your code has 1100px for sea-green, which I can see and I am following the overriding rules you mentioned, is 1600 too large? is this is the reason I am unable to see it on my screen?

I don’t know. I can’t see your screen. Try increasing from 1100px in steps of 100px, to see which values work and which do not. But remember that there is a huge range of screen sizes available, so even if your screen is narrower than 1600px, other people will have wider ones.
